# Spring boot actuator with spring boot 1.5.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am upgrading my spring-boot to 1.5.4 and also using actuator for the health check. The build is successful but when i run the application i am getting the below error:

```
2017-09-05 14:18:19.523 [                                    ]#[NO_TRACE]  WARN 26855 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpointHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint@1948ea69' bean method 
public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
to {[/loggers || /loggers.json],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json],custom=[]}: There is already 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint@1948ea69' bean method
public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.get(java.lang.String) mapped.

2017-09-05 14:18:19.526 [                                    ]#[NO_TRACE]  INFO 26855 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-09-05 14:18:19.537 [                                    ]#[NO_TRACE]  INFO 26855 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-09-05 14:18:19.563 [                                    ]#[NO_TRACE]  INFO 26855 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-09-05 14:18:19.577 [                                    ]#[NO_TRACE] ERROR 26855 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpointHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint@1948ea69' bean method 
public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
to {[/loggers || /loggers.json],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json],custom=[]}: There is already 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint@1948ea69' bean method
public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.get(java.lang.String) mapped.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
at com.ge.apm.viewproxy.Application.main(Application.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Below is all the maven dependency related to spring:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Cloud -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Util -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ASCII Doc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-context-support.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Versions for different packages:

```
    <spring-context-support.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-context-support.version>
    <spring-restdocs.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring-restdocs.version>
```

I have verified and the actuator class refers to the 1.5.4 version of spring boot and i don't have any other version of spring boot referred in my application.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Please post your Maven or Gradle file. Did you also upgrade spring-cloud-dependencies?

Comment: Updated the maven dependencies. I did not upgrade spring-cloud. I am using spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector and its pointing to 1.2.4

Comment: For starters stop mixing spring versions... You are mixing 4.0, 4.1 and 4.3 jars. Remove the `spring-context-support-version. Next to that you have duplicate dependencies etc. so start by cleaning your pom.

Comment: Seems you are correct. The spring-webmvc (4.0.8) version was conflicting some how with sprint-boot. I removed the exclusive versioning and now reading spring version from the parent e.g. 4.3.9 which resolved the issue.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Can you put your comment as an answer so that i can mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies are a mess.

1. You are including additional dependencies that are already in the starters.
2. You are mixing, at least, Spring versions 4.0, 4.1 and 4.3.

Instead of all the individual dependencies I suggest to remove them and use the starters.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Cloud -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Util -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- ASCII Doc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The solution that given above looks good. Apart from this, you can also exclude the maven artifacts those are conflicting to each other. (From Dependency Hierarchies). Something like, add exclusion. <exclusions></exclusions>